# Adding String Literal to Generated Barcode image

Tags: c#, barcode

I'm creating a web app that generates barcodes that uses information that's databound. That information is a name from a database.

The barcode generates correctly, but I want to add text to it.

Here is my code for the barcode generator.

```
protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (ListItem item in BarCode.Items)
   {
      if (item.Selected)
      {
          string barCode = Barcode + txtCode.Text;
          System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
          using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(barCode.Length * 50, 90))
          {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
            {
               Font oFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 18);
               PointF point = new PointF(3f, 3f);
               SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
               SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
               graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);
               graphics.DrawString(barCode, oFont, blackBrush, point);
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

                Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
             }

                  plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);
         }
     }

   }

}
```

I want to add

> "QTY:_____________"

underneath the barcode when it's generated. Although I believe the formatting of the barcode is limited to the code and I don't believe I can create a string literal

```
string lit = "QTY:_______________";
```

and add it to the barcode string:

```
string barCode = Barcode + txtCode.Text + Environement.NewLine + lit;
```

Is it possible to add that underneath programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right You don't need to add text into code, you need to print some text under bar code. Just add into:

```
using (Graphics graphics
```

somthig like this:

```
// put coordinates here:
RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(70, 90, 90, 50);


graphics.DrawString(lit , new Font("Tahoma",8), Brushes.Black, rectf);
```

Comment: Yes, I believe it is something like this. Although when I add it it doesn't work, instead I added a new block and added this code and now it prints the "QTY:__________" without the barcode, so the idea is there. I just now need to figure out how to add it in the original block. I don't know why your example won't work though as intended.

Comment: @d_li1121, did you adjust coordinates of rectf?, show the new version of code

Comment: Yea I'm messing around with the coordinates, but I'm fairly new at this, so I just keep getting it behind the barcode.  `RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(20, 40, 40, 30);` I'm researching as well to understand the formatting.

Comment: I understand how the coordinates work, but I believe I'm not seeing the wanted results, is because of the size of the rectangle of the barcode. If I change the size of the barcode, I know see everything in its entirety overlapping. So, now I'm in the right direction at least.

Comment: Of course, I was so invested in the rectangle coordinates, that I overlooked the Barcode Rectangle length itself. I got it to work, thank you!